# Jenkins cancel api return 302 but does not cancel the queued jobs: ( Jobs which are not started and still in pending status)

Tags: jenkins, queue

We are using node request module to call POST /queue/cancelItem?id={queueId} , as a response we are getting 302 status which is correct as per documentation , But Jenkins queued job is not getting canceled and gets completed later on.

PS: i can cancel Jenkins queued jobs from jenkins UI, without any issue also I can cancel the started Job from UI as well from node request module.